# Dataframe filter issue, how to do?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter, apache-spark-sql

Env: Spark 1.6, Scala

My dataframe is like bellow

DF=
DT        col1 col2
----------|---|----
2017011011| AA| BB
2017011011| CC| DD
2017011015| PP| BB
2017011015| QQ| DD
2017011016| AA| BB
2017011016| CC| DD
2017011017| PP| BB
2017011017| QQ| DD

How can I filter to get result like SQL - `select * from DF where dt> (select distinct dt from DF order by dt desc limit 3)`

output have last 3 dates

2017011015 |PP |BB
2017011015 |QQ |DD
2017011016 |AA |BB
2017011016 |CC |DD
2017011017 |PP |BB
2017011017 |QQ |DD

Thanks
Hossain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested on Spark 1.6.1

```
import sqlContext.implicit._
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (2017011011, "AA", "BB"),
  (2017011011, "CC", "DD"),
  (2017011015, "PP", "BB"),
  (2017011015, "QQ", "DD"),
  (2017011016, "AA", "BB"),
  (2017011016, "CC", "DD"),
  (2017011017, "PP", "BB"),
  (2017011017, "QQ", "DD")
)).select(
  $"_1".as("DT"),
  $"_2".as("col1"),
  $"_3".as("col2")
) 

val dates = df.select($"DT")
  .distinct()
  .orderBy(-$"DT")
  .map(_.getInt(0))
  .take(3)

val result = df.filter(dates.map($"DT" === _).reduce(_ || _))
result.show()
```